# has_one through association or alternative way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not sure how to setup the tables and the relationships for what I'm trying to achieve. I thought I need a has_one through relationship but I saw a few posts advising against that.

What I'm trying to achieve is a shop creates a list of their services and their staff select the services they do from this list.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class User
 has_many :staff
  # user and shop have relationship via roles (not shown for simplicity)
end

class Shop
  has_many :staff
  has_many :services
  # user and shop have relationship via roles (not shown for simplicity)
end

class Service
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :staff through: :staff_services
end

class Staff
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :services through: :staff_services
end

class StaffService
  belongs_to :staff
  # ? has_one :service through: :shop
  # ? belongs_to :service
end
```

I'm not sure how to set the relationship for StaffServices so that a staff is only able to select services from the shop they are a staff member of.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a many-to-many associations between Staff and Services. I believe you want `belongs_to :service` in your `StaffService` table. This can be simplified to isolate the association you're working with as such:

```
class Service
  has_many :staff, through: :staff_services
end

class Staff
  has_many :services, through: :staff_services
end

class StaffService
  belongs_to :staff
  belongs_to :service
end
```

I don't mean to suggest the other associations you've got in your example are invalid or wrong in any way--I just wanted to show only the many-to-many part. The associations you already have up there between Shop & Staff, and Shop & Services will allow you to build scopes easily that will restrict the set of Staff and Services involved.

If you haven't already, I suggest giving the [Rails Guide to Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) a careful read.

Comment: the way you suggest is how I was originally thinking to do it. But if doing it this way won't it mean that Staff could potentially have a Service that is from a different shop?

Comment: Well, you're defining the shape of the tables, not the restrictions on the data therein. If you want to prevent a Staff from having a Service from a different shop, you can prepare a scope that only returns the services that come from the same shop and the staff.